# Proportion of the variables in each observation that satisfy certain conditions in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, data-cleaning, proc-sql

**HAVE** is a SAS data set with 1700 observations and ~1,000 variables. There are three "types" of variables beyond the id. They are denoted by different prefixes. Here is a subset of the file:

```
id    a_dog b_dog c_dog a_cat b_cat c_cat a_mouse b_mouse c_mouse ...
prsn1     1    -1    -2     2     2     0       1       4       1   
prsn2    -1    -3     4     2     2    -1       0      -1      -1   
...
```

I need to calculate the proportion of values that are above, below, or equal to zero for each respondent, by the type of variable (i.e., (**a_**, **b_**, or **c_**). The solution should append these new variables to the file:

```
... prop_a_gt0 prop_a_lt0 prop_a_eq0 prop_b_gt0 prop_b_lt0 prop_b_eq0 prop_c_gt0 prop_c_lt0 prop_c_eq0
...     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.6667     0.3333     0.0000     0.3333     0.3333     0.3333
...     0.3333     0.3333     0.3333     0.3333     0.6667     0.0000     0.3333     0.6667     0.0000
```

Note how **prop_b_gt0**, for example, is 0.6667 for *prsn1* because two of the three **b_** variables in the *prsn1* row have values greater than 0.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this systematically. Perhaps there's a way to combine arrays with a proc sql step? Any solution welcome!

Comment: Why have inconsistent naming constructs ?  **b_prop_gt0** would be more aligned with the existing **b_dog b_cat b_mouse** variables.  Also, are you saying there a ~333 response topics (dog, cat, mouse, … 333rd topic) ?

Comment: that would also work - I'll revise if that's easier. Yes, there are ~330 topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an array you will need to loop through the array and count the number greater (and possibly count the number non-missing).

```
data want;
  set have ;
  array a a_: ;
  numerator=0;
  denominator=0;
  do index=1 to dim(a);
    numerator=sum(numerator,a[index]>0);
    denominator=sum(denominator,not missing(a[index]));
  end;
  prob_a_gt0=numerator/denominator;
  drop index numerator denominator;
run;
```

Just replicate the block of code for the B and C variables also.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of more than three arrays (grouped by variable name suffix A, B, C) a macro will help ensure there are no typos or stray edits that can happen during copy and paste (code replication).

Suppose a macro **compute_proportions** emits code that loops over a variable array defined in a DATA Step.  The code generator counts each conditional states met by criteria during the loop and calculates the proportion after looping.

```
* simulate data;

data have;
  array a a_1-a_300;  * for simplicity, presume 1 to 300 correspond to dog, cat, mouse, ...;
  array b b_1-b_300;
  array c c_1-c_300;

  call streaminit(123);

  do id = 1 to 10;
    do _n_ = 1 to dim(a);
      a (_n_) = ceil(rand('uniform', 9)) - 5;
      b (_n_) = ceil(rand('uniform', 9)) - 5;
      c (_n_) = ceil(rand('uniform', 9)) - 5;
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

%macro compute_proportions(array=, prefix=);

  _lt = 0; %* <0 count;
  _eq = 0; %* =0 count;
  _gt = 0; %* >0 count;
  _n  = 0;

  do _index = 1 to dim(&array);

    _v = &array(_n_);

    if not missing(_v) then do;
      _lt + _v < 0;
      _eq + _v = 0;
      _gt + _v > 0;
      _n + 1;
    end;

  end;

  if _n > 0 then do;
    &prefix.prop_lt0 = _lt / _n;
    &prefix.prop_eq0 = _eq / _n;
    &prefix.prop_gt0 = _gt / _n;
  end;

  drop _lt _eq _gt _index _v _n;
%mend;

data want;
  set have;

  array a a_:; * all variables whose names start with a_ can be array referenced during step;
  array b b_:;
  array c c_:;

  %compute_proportions (array=a, prefix=a_)
  %compute_proportions (array=b, prefix=b_)
  %compute_proportions (array=c, prefix=c_)
run;
```